# Scheduled annotation

Tags: java, spring, аннотации

Как использовать scheduled  аннотация из спринга?. допустим есть какой то метод который удаляет данные из БД MYSQL можно ли сделать так что с помощю аннотации Scheduled  добавить время допустим каждый 5 часов удалить данные

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */5 * * * ?")
public void deleteSomeData() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое.если не сложно объясните что писали внутри аннотации

Comment: Инструкция [cron](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), указывающая на необходимость запускать метод каждые 5 часов.

Comment: спасибо огромное

Comment: а как сделать чтобы удалил через один минут.

Comment: Как вызывать раз в минуту?

Comment: да для проверки метода

Comment: `cron = "* * * * * ?"`

Comment: спасибо Вам Большое

Comment: @Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * ?")
    public void deleteBadWordByScheduled() {
    badWordRepository.delete(2);
написал так но не удаляет возможно неправильно написал

    }

Comment: сразу давал id данных

Comment: У вас xml- или java-конфигурация контекста? [Включали поддержку этой аннотации](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling-enable-annotation-support)?

Comment: конфигурация java

Comment: Тогда надо её аннотировать с помощью `@EnableScheduling`.

Comment: спасибо сейчас попробую

Comment: а как вызывать что писать в аннотации...@Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * ?" там вот так писали а здесь как

Comment: Ничего не надо. Перейдите по ссылке в комментарии, там есть пример.

Comment: ок спасибо еще раз